# MYSQL replace a cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

Hi guys basically a friend wants to run a query that basically:

If mpn column contains hsun then replace the supplier id cell with the number 4 in a table called product

We've tried

```
UPDATE product SET supplier_id='4' WHERE mpn='%hsun%';
```

But keeps returning 0 items updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE mpn LIKE '%husn%'
```

instead.  `%` and `_` are plain characters with no special meaning when you're doing straight equality (`=`) testing. It's only when you use `LIKE` that they become wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE product SET supplier_id='4' WHERE mpn LIKE '%hsun%';
```

equal sign will try to match the exact string, where LIKE would treat % as wildcard